# Can you have a for loop with a -1 step in Python, like you can in VBA?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am converting some VBA code into Python and I came across the following loop which steps -1

```
For k = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
```

What is the equivalent of a -1 Step in Python?

Comment: Please read some documentation.

Comment: Did someone shutdown the docs.python.org to protest the US SOPA legislation?

Comment: Surely it's quicker to type that into Google than Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to literally translate it use [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) (or [`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange) in Python 2.x):

```
for k in range(i-1, 0, -1):
  ...
```

However, if `k` is an index in an array (i.e. you read from `someArray[k]` in your original code) you should use [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) instead of fiddling with the numbers:

```
for elem in reversed(someArray):
   # Do something with elem
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning *reverse()* which was designed to handle reverse iteration more cleanly than *range()* with a negative step.

Comment: It should be `reversed` instead of `reverse`, fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

```
for k in range(i-1, 0, -1):
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in iterating over the values in reverse order, then use `reversed()`:

```
>>> a = list(range(5))
>>> for i in reversed(a):
...     print i
... 
4
3
2
1
0
```